# RTP AAC timestamps issue

Tags: c++, audio, audio-streaming, rtp

I'm trying to stream AAC audio to Wowza server via RTP. I managed to make it work but I hear alternately the sound very fast and then a 1s blank. Sample rate is 22050 and frames per packet is 1024.

Currently my timestamps are generated like that :

```
long _timestamp;

//--- called each time I have to send a new AAC packet ---//
-(void) updateTimestamp{
    if(! _timestamp)
        _timestamp = random();
    else
        _timestamp += 1024;
    rtptime = big_endian(_timestamp);
}
```

is it correct ? I don't know why the output is that weird ans any help would be apreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the purpose of the code but the `if (!_timestamp)` block is unlikely to get hit since _timestamp is not initialized to 0

Comment: hum, it works on objecive-c++ but you can replace it by
"if (_timestamp == 0)"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the logic is correct, but instead of long, use unsigned long, so that it takes care of rounding when unsigned long reaches max value.